# Retrieving message body using Emailmessage class

Tags: c#, web-services, email, class

I have to retrieve the body of an email sent and store it in a shared folder.
I have the following code sample to retrieve attachments from the email and store it.

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(item.Id.ToString()),
new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));

foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
{

    if (attachment is FileAttachment)
    {
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

        // Load attachment contents into a file.
        fileAttachment.Load("C:\\CodeCopy\\Email\\temp\\" + fileAttachment.Name);
```

Similarly if I want to use EmailMessage.body property how do I use it.
I am a beginner, so please give a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EmailMessage.Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.body.aspx) property to get an object representing the body of your message, then call its [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.messagebody.tostring.aspx) method to get the body contents as a string, and write that string to a file:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(item.Id.ToString()),
    new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(String.Format(
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"C:\CodeCopy\Email\temp\{0}.body.txt",
       item.Id.ToString().Replace('\\', '_')))) {
    writer.Write(message.Body.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. I also observe that there is a property called EmailMessage.save(). I realized that according to my requirement, I have to save the message as a .msg file. Can I use this property(save) to save the message as .msg file? If so how do I use it?

Comment: Alas, as far as I know [Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.save.aspx) can only copy the message to an Exchange folder, not to a actual file.

Comment: Hi,
It throws this particular error while executing the above code.Does the code attempt to create a new folder on the fly based on the message body?
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\CodeCopy\Email\temp\AAMkAGRiYW[lots of random characters snipped]wrGAAAw2bxUAAAAThcVX

Thanks,
Kruthika

Comment: @Kruthika, that's because the message identifier contains backslashes (I forgot about that). I edited my answer so they're replaced by underscores, it should work as expected now.